# If a disc is rolling on a surface, how do you verify that no slip occurs?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

If I have the values for the coefficient of static friction (0.1) and all the other variables, how do I verify that no slip occurs?

Comment: if you have angular and linear speeds, then prove them equal.

Comment: Otherwise show that the moment of static friction can cause a rotational acceleration greater than the linear one coming from all forces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rolling disc.]

Mathematically the no-slip condition is represented by:

$$v=\omega R$$

Where $v$ is translational (linear) velocity, $\omega$ is angular (rotational) velocity and $R$ is disc radius.

Assuming no air drag we can see that no *net forces* or *net moments* act on the disc. By Newton's First Law this means the object's state of motion (both *translational* and *rotational*) will remain 'forever' unchanged. The value of the friction coefficient has no influence here.

Now consider a different scenario:

[image: Rolling with slipping.]

At 'launch' ($t=0$):

$$v_0<\omega_0 R$$

This causes slippage and an active friction force $F_F$ to arise, which points in the opposite direction of the relative motion between the disc and floor surfaces, as shown.

Assuming the friction coefficient is a kinetic one ($\mu_k$), the friction force is modelled as:

$$F_F=\mu_k mg$$

This friction force has an effect on both the state of translation and rotation:

It caused a *linear acceleration* acc.:

$$ma=F_F$$

Or:

$$a=\mu_k g$$

The force $F_F$ also exerts a moment $\tau$ about the CoG of the disc which causes *angular deceleration*:

$$\tau= -F_FR$$

And with:

$$I\alpha=\tau=-\mu_k mg$$

Or:

$$\alpha=-\frac{\mu_k mg}{I}$$

Where $\alpha=\frac{d\omega}{dt}$ is the angular deceleration and $I$ is the inertial moment of the disc.

These accelerations/decelerations over time respectively increase the value of $v_0$, while decreasing $\omega_0$, until:

$$v=\omega R$$

One can also imagine the opposite scenario, where:

$$v_0>\omega_0 R$$

The friction force will then point in the opposite direction, $v_0$ will decrease and $\omega_0$ will increase, again until:

$$v=\omega R$$